# H2 JDBC Prepared Statement Exception

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I am attempting to select all of the tables in the default schema, 'PUBLIC' using a prepared statement and parameters for TABLE_CATALOG and TABLE_SCHEMA. When I create a prepared statement I get an error back from the system and it doesn't make any sense. If I specify TABLE_CATALOG without TABLE_SCHEMA it works perfectly. Also, if I specify TABLE_SCHEMA without TABLE_CATALOG it also works without issue. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_CATALOG, 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_CATALOG = ?, TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
```

Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL

```
statement "SELECT 
    TABLE_CATALOG, 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_CATALOG = ?,[*] TABLE_SCHEMA = ?"; SQL statement:
SELECT 
    TABLE_CATALOG, 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_CATALOG = ?, TABLE_SCHEMA = ? [42000-193]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:191)
at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:530)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:257)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:287)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:310)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
```

Comment: I just realized I forgot the AND in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
TABLE_CATALOG = ?, TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
```

should be

```
TABLE_CATALOG = ? AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
```